# Using Func, Action, and Generics For Ambiguous Property Assignment

Tags: c#, generics

I am looping through a `SqlDataReader`, and setting the properties of an object. I am doing a lot of repetitive work, and I was wondering if this was a good place to use the 4.0 delegate framework and generics. I am uninterested in frameworks (entity, MVC etc.) that blackbox this.

`ConvertReaderToMyCustomType` is my current method, and the associated extension method `HasColumn`.

```
public static List<MyCustomType> ConvertReaderToMyCustomType(this SqlDataReader reader)
{
    var tempCollection = new List<MyCustomType>();
    int colX = reader.GetOrdinal("PropertyX");        
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        MyCustomType tracking = new MyCustomType();
        if (reader.HasColumn("PropertyX"))
        {
            tracking.PropertyX = reader[colX];
            //etc.
        }
    }
}

public static bool HasColumn(this IDataRecord dr, string columnName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (dr.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Futhermore, what if tracking.PropertyX is a DateTime? How does one handling the casting in a generic fashion if there are multiple properties of variious types?

Comment: I know you said you're not interested in frameworks, but Dapper does this and much more and it's open source if you want to look at the code.

Comment: I looked through it, its just too expansive. I am looking for a less is more solution.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're looking for `Func` or `Action` to come in to play, you should be able to accomplish what you're after by making your convert method a generic method and using reflection.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: @user3010406 That's funny because Dapper is the less is more of ORMs.  Your code is either going to be specific to your entities or you'll end up with something similar to Dapper.  Now, if this is to learn how to do it then sure knock yourself out, but if this is for production code that others have to help maintain and has a deadline, then why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: google dynamic casting. I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe14d396-bc35-4f98-851d-ce3c8663cd79/dynamic-casting-in-c-at-runtime?forum=csharplanguage)